# rpivotTable и nvd3 rcharts в одном приложении

Tags: r, shiny

Пытаюсь сделать приложение содержащие в себе одновременно

`rpivotTable` и `nvd3 rcharts`

Все работает , но при попытке показать графики из rpivotTable,появляется ошибка

> An error occurred rendering the PivotTable results.

## Пример

UI

```
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)
library(rpivotTable)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  showOutput('plot1',lib = "nvd3"),
  rpivotTableOutput('pivot1', width = "100%", height = "500px"))  
)
```

Server

```
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)
library(rpivotTable)

df=data.frame(A=c(1:10),B=c(-10:-1),C=c("x",rep(c("x","y","z"),3)))
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$pivot1 <- renderRpivotTable({
    rpivotTable(data =df ,
                width="100%", height="500px")
  })

  output$plot1=renderChart2({
    myform <- as.formula(paste('A','~','B'))

    n2 <- nPlot(myform,  group ="C", data = df, type = 'multiBarChart')
    n2$chart(margin = list(left = 100))
    n2$chart(reduceXTicks = F)
    n2$set(width = 800, height = 500) 

    print(n2)
  })
  })
```

В итоге я получаю 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если удалить из приложения все что связано с `rCharts` графики в сводной показываются :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Версии используемых пакетов

```
rpivotTable_0.1.5.7                    
rCharts_0.4.2    
shiny_0.12.2.9005
```

Есть ли возможность исправить данный момент?

В отладчике вижу следующую ошибку

```
TypeError: a.axisTimeFormat.multi is not a function
    at e.i.initParams (c3.min.js:1)
    at e.i.init (c3.min.js:1)
    at new d (c3.min.js:1)
    at Object.k.generate (c3.min.js:1)
    at Object.renderer (c3_renderers.coffee:129)
    at t.fn.pivot (pivot.coffee:546)
    at pivot.coffee:835
```

Оригинал вопроса на [EN_SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33694588/an-error-occurred-rendering-the-pivottable-results)

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашелся вариант предложенный @NicE [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33694588/an-error-occurred-rendering-the-pivottable-results/35515856#35515856).

Проблема возникает в силу двойной загрузки библиотеки `n3`.
Во избежание этого , возможно рисовать `rCharts` в `iframe`, что бы `js` и `css` не пересекались.

Для этого можно использовать `uiOutput/renderUI` в `shiny` и `show` в `rCharts`

## Пример :

```
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)
library(rpivotTable)

df=data.frame(A=c(1:10),B=c(-10:-1),C=c("x",rep(c("x","y","z"),3)))

ui <-shinyUI(fluidPage(
        uiOutput('plot1'),
        rpivotTableOutput('pivot1')  
))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
        output$pivot1 <- renderRpivotTable({
                rpivotTable(data =df)
        })

        output$plot1=renderUI({
                myform <- as.formula(paste('A','~','B'))
                n2 <- nPlot(myform,  group ="C", data = df, type = 'multiBarChart')
                n2$chart(margin = list(left = 100))
                n2$chart(reduceXTicks = F)
                HTML(paste(capture.output(n2$show('iframesrc', cdn = TRUE)), collapse = '\n'))

        })
})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```